# how to feed variable or json file to curl

Tags: linux, powershell, unix, curl

I have seen many variants already on the forum but none worked for me, can anyone enlighten me with the correct curl -d syntax for the command to work ( properly get the data from $variable_json) ?  Putting directly the text from varible into curl works without problem, but with variable it gives error.  This variable is composed dynamically on the below pattern and must be able to call curl -d either by variable or json file.

```
$variable_json = '{\"customDomains\":[\"internal.test10.com\",\"external.test10.com\"],\"aadInfo\":{\"loginUrl\":\"https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer\"},\"name\":\"App-Test10\",\"category\":\"SAASDB_CATEGORY_COLLABORATION\",\"hostingPlatform\":2,\"score\":5,\"note\":\"This app was added by myself through API\",\"suffixSupport\":true,\"domains\":[],\"ipv4\":[],\"ipv6\":[],\"isCustomApp\":true}'
```

< $variable_json has already been enclosed and escaped with ' and " as for the variable above to be the final output needed >

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://company_domain.portal.cloudappsecurity.com/api/v1/discovery/app_catalog/create_custom_app/' -H "Authorization: Bearer $Token" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "$variable_json"

or

curl -L -X POST 'https://company_domain.portal.cloudappsecurity.com/api/v1/discovery/app_catalog/create_custom_app/' -H "Authorization: Bearer $Token" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '@C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\the_file.json'
```

The answer can be for unix or powershell, any variant is fine.

Thank you

Edit:

The error received is:

> {"name":[{"error":"This field is
> required","errorMessageCode":"CONSOLE_FORMS_FIELD_REQUIRED"}],"category":[{"error":"This
> field is
> required","errorMessageCode":"CONSOLE_FORMS_FIELD_REQUIRED"}],"customDomains":[{"error":"This
> field is
> required","errorMessageCode":"CONSOLE_FORMS_FIELD_REQUIRED"}],"note":[{"error":"This
> field is
> required","errorMessageCode":"CONSOLE_FORMS_FIELD_REQUIRED"}],"hostingPlatform":[{"error":"This
> field is
> required","errorMessageCode":"CONSOLE_FORMS_FIELD_REQUIRED"}],"score":[{"error":"This
> field is
> required","errorMessageCode":"CONSOLE_FORMS_FIELD_REQUIRED"}],"error":true}

Which is weird, because if I put the data from the json file by hand, it works without issues.  My whole problem is that the command just wont parse properly the variable/file.json for the "-d pamater"

Comment: What does "dynamic and accessible" mean to you? You are already feeding a variable to curl with `-d $variable_json`. Is that giving you an error?

Comment: Yes, it gives error. And while the same text is put directly ( without variable ) it works

Comment: What error do you get? And can you post the full working curl command?

Comment: I have added the error in the ticket, but I can't add the full command with token as it is a breach of security if I do :(

Comment: Ok, so can you add a *redacted* example of a curl command that works? Just put asterisks where there's secret values or use dummy data instead.

Comment: curl -L -X POST 'https://*****.portal.cloudappsecurity.com/api/v1/discovery/app_catalog/create_custom_app/' -H "Authorization: Bearer *****" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"customDomains\":[\"internal.test10.com\",\"external.test10.com\"],\"aadInfo\":{\"loginUrl\":\"https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer\"},\"name\":\"App-Test10\",\"category\":\"SAASDB_CATEGORY_COLLABORATION\",\"hostingPlatform\":2,\"score\":5,\"note\":\"This app was added by me through API\",\"suffixSupport\":true,\"domains\":[],\"ipv4\":[],\"ipv6\":[],\"isCustomApp\":true}'

Comment: try 
`curl -L -X POST 'https://company_domain.portal.cloudappsecurity.com/api/v1/discovery/app_catalog/create_custom_app/' -H "Authorization: Bearer $Token" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "${variable_json}"`

Comment: same error :(  unfortuenally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just abandonated the issue and put microsoft Lv3 to do it.

They are using cmdlets iwth some @[Ordered] json body....crap i've never seen